# "He was drinking from leaves." VS "He was drinking off of leaves." | Why "...off of...."?

Tags: usage, phrasal-verbs

**"It rained so much over the time that he was away. He was just drinking off of leaves."** [Lost dog found](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=R-sSiwtps6E) (see:1:08-1:13)

I understand the dog was drinking rainwater from the leaves. So, why not simply say **"...drinking from leaves."** but **"....drinking off of leaves..."**? Why do we need **"off"** and **"of"**?

Comment: We don't need 'off of', which is informal and conversational. People don't always talk in a formal way like books.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey, Thanks for the comment, I understand now it is informal, but it is still correct, isn't it? I mean we can use it, too, can't we? That is what I want to find out.

Comment: Formal and informal usages are obviously possible.

Comment: In Britain, I associate 'off of' with the London area; from her speech, the dog owner seems to come from there.

Comment: For Australian English I would regard it as wrong. I can't speak for other regions.

Comment: @KateBunting - I used to inveigh against 'off of', considering it an ignorant Americanism or Cockney solecism, until I did some homework and found it in Pepys and that the OED quotes it from 1450 onwards. Merriam-Webster’s Dictionary of English Usage says the “off of” construction lost its respectability in the last quarter of the 19th century. Although it has “faded into the past” in Britain, M-W notes, it has become idiomatic in the US.

Comment: That said, even ignoring the awkward "off of" construction, isn't there still a difference between "drink off sth" and "drink from sth"? (The former meaning "drink off the surface of something" and the latter "drink out of something shaped like a vessel"). I wouldn't use "drinking from leaves" unless the leaves were shaped to hold water like a cup.